# How to make Qt and Qtcreator link the libraries statically instead of dynamic?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I know it might be a question similar to many others, but after searching for many times and failing to get a definitive and effective solution I'm having to ask this question.

I'm using **Qt 5.2.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 570 MB)**, and I have already made my programming, and it's all done. But now I want to distribute it as .exe file to my colleagues, but to do so without complication and to avoid having to distribute dll files I need to build the program using static linking.

Could you please describe how I can make **Qt 5.2.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 570 MB)** build the whole program using static linking?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a static version of Qt?

Comment: What do you mean static version of Qt? I only installed **Qt 5.2.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 570 MB)**, I didn't check if that's static.

Comment: @UmNyobe: yeah, the OP must have that if bundling up the qt libraries are also necessary. In that case, he will need to built Qt on his own though.

Comment: @the_naive: that is not static.

Comment: Do you know how I can build Qt on my own?

Comment: It is possible to build Qt statically as long as your application is developed with a QT commercial licence or being developed under the LGPL. Otherwise, you will need to link dynamically.

Comment: ...or under a (free) license compatible to LGPL.

Comment: @the_naive: I updated my answer respectively.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld and ManuelH: true, good note. I added that to my answer for completeness. Thanks for mentioning here!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `CONFIG` variable for this with qmake:

```
CONFIG += static
```

or

```
CONFIG += staticlib
```

However, you will need to make sure that you have all the libraries that you wish to bundle up, available as static.

This includes the Qt framework itself as well if you comply with the license to do so. The official installation only sets up dynamic libraries (.dll files), so you would need to build Qt on your own to accomplish this.

You could use the following commands to build `Qt` statically for your own purpose:

```
configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -static
qmake -r
nmake
```

Note that in general when building third-party Qt softwares like yours, you better invoke `qmake` with the following parameter to pass your environment properly:

```
qmake -r -spec win32-msvc2010
```

Please also noted that as Frank and ManuelH wrote in the comment, static linkage is not allowed if your application is not free licensed either a LGPL or at least compatible to LGPL, nor do you use commercial license for Qt. It is better to make sure about this before picking up your approach.

Once that is done, you can use the `LIBS` variable in the regular way, as in: pass the path of your static library to it along with the library name, so something like this:

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/the/static/library -lstaticlibraryname
```

Note that the static library name passed to the `-l` parameter should not contain the static library extension, for instance `.lib` on Windows.

As a fallback, you can always link other libraries statically, and put the Qt dll files beside the executable, and you deploy the folder as a "package". That is probably the easier way for you to go.

Comment: It does nothing. Exe is still same small and still can't start on another computer. I have downloaded Qt 5.7 for MinGW. It contains both directory bin with <name>.dll and directory lib with lib<name>.a, so the static libs are clearly there. Yet, neither `static` nor `staticlib` works.

Comment: Once one uses a static build of Qt, as you correctly state one needs to, then there's no point in adding anything special to the project configuration itself. It will be statically linked to Qt, and possibly also statically linked to the language runtime if Qt was configured with `-static-runtime`. The parameters of the chosen Qt build determine what happens to the project you build using that particular Qt build. No need for `CONFIG += static`, it's a no-op.