# How to force libraries to link statically in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, static-libraries, qmake, static-linking

When one wants to link statically all available libraries using g++,
this person passes **-static** flag to the compiler.

But how to do it from Qt Creator?

Firstly, I tried this advice:
[How to make Qt and Qtcreator link the libraries statically instead of dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799161/how-to-make-qt-and-qtcreator-link-the-libraries-statically-instead-of-dynamic)

The post suggests to use

```
CONFIG += static
```

But that just doesn't work.

Secondly, I tried another approach and added the following line to my .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -static
```

That didn't solve the problem either.
I analyzed compiler output and discovered:

-static flag is added only when compiling sources to object files.
But when building executable, this flag is absent.

Here are the exact compiler commands that I copied from the compiler output tab:

```
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -static -g -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I..\..\..\ASSETS\PROG_CPP\MY_CPP\2016\test -I. -I..\..\..\icu\dist\include -I..\..\5.7\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o ..\..\..\ASSETS\PROG_CPP\MY_CPP\2016\test\main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\test.exe debug/main.o  -LC:\icu\dist\lib -lsicuio -lsicuin -lsiculx -lsicule -lsicuuc C:\icu\dist\lib\sicudt.a -lpthread -lm
```

How to force Qmake to add -static to all commands?

Answer (score 7):

The solution was quite obvious, as I discovered later. 
There is a special variable in Qmake that is responsible for linker flags: QMAKE_LFLAGS.
So all I had to do is to add the following to the .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static
```

Comment: It is not helpful in my case, but this: `unix: LIBS += -Wl,-Bstatic -l<name> -Wl,-Bdynamic` is ok

Comment: On Windows I get unrecognized option /static

Comment: On MacOS it does not work because other system libraries cannot be static.

Comment: Also not available in CMake-based projects.